# Print a specific key (e.g., third key) from a Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I'm not sure why I am struggling to find this answer, but I am. I want to print the third key and item from a Python dictionary. I don't want to for loop and print all values like many other questions seem to ask. Simply, I just want `dictionaryData.keys()[2]`. I know this is incorrect, but this is what I am trying to accomplish.

What is the correct way to obtain the third key from a dictionary?

Comment: You must convert it to a list first `list(dictionaryData.keys())[2]`.

Comment: Use ordereddict

Comment: In (not so) old versions of python, dics don't conserve the order of the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the third key and its associated value you could do this:

```
d = {1:'A',2:'B',3:'C'}

print(*list(d.items())[2])
```

**Output:**

```
3 C
```

**Note:**

This assumes that there at least 3 key/value pairs in the dictionary

**Or:**

If you just want to be weird then:

```
_, _, (k, v), *_ = d.items()
print(k, v)
```